# Acumatica - creating a simple detail screen with header

Tags: acumatica

Acumatica is seriously gonna make me cry. I have followed the tutorial in T100 to create a simple inquiry screen. When I open it, the screen is blank. I can see the layout in design view, when I load the screen it is blank.

My graph:

```
 public class QLInventoryMaint : PXGraph<QLInventoryMaint>
{
    public QLInventoryMaint()
    {
        ResponseRec.Cache.AllowInsert = false;
        ResponseRec.Cache.AllowDelete = false;
        ResponseRec.Cache.AllowUpdate = false;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class StrainFilter : IBqlTable
    {

        #region DisplayID
        public abstract class displayID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected String _DisplayID;
        [PXString(4)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Display ID")]
        public virtual String DisplayID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DisplayID;
            }
            set
            {
                this._DisplayID = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }

    public PXCancel<StrainFilter> Cancel;
    public PXFilter<StrainFilter> StrainFilterRec;
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXSelectReadonly<StrainResult, Where<StrainResult.displayID, Equal<Current<StrainFilter.displayID>>>> ResponseRec;

}
```

My page:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FormDetail.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="SO301010.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_SO301010" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormDetail.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%" PrimaryView="StrainFilterRec" TypeName="PX.Objects.SO.QLInventoryMaint">
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" 
        Width="100%" DataMember="StrainFilterRec" TabIndex="2500">
        <Template>
            <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True"/>
            <px:PXTextEdit ID="edDisplayID" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="DisplayID" DefaultLocale="">
            </px:PXTextEdit>
        </Template>
    </px:PXFormView>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont3" ContentPlaceHolderID="phG" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" 
        Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Details" TabIndex="3500" TemporaryFilterCaption="Filter Applied">
<EmptyMsg ComboAddMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter or modify parameters above to see records here." NamedComboMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter or modify parameters above to see records here." NamedComboAddMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter or modify parameters above to see records here." FilteredMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here." FilteredAddMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here." NamedFilteredMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter to see records here." NamedFilteredAddMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter to see records here." AnonFilteredMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here." AnonFilteredAddMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here."></EmptyMsg>
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataKeyNames="DisplayID" DataMember="ResponseRec">
                <Columns>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Name" Width="200px">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Abbreviation">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ClonesCount" TextAlign="Right">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="PlantsCount" TextAlign="Right">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="HarvestedCount" TextAlign="Right">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="WetFlowerWeight" TextAlign="Right">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="DryFlowerWeight" TextAlign="Right">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                </Columns>
            </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
    </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

I wanted originally to create a lookup screen with no database fields, but I was getting the same result. I decided just o follow tutorial and create inquiry screen. I hate this framework.

Comment: setup seems straight forward. Can you include the page file for this graph in the example? As for the framework, it does require a learning curve. Once you get use to the key components you need it is very easy and flexible to work with. Even more so compared to other ERP systems I have worked with.

Comment: @Brendan I added aspx code. Dunno man, I went through T100, T300 and halfway through T200 and still end up spending a whole day on stupid things like this one.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the `Current<>` display ID is not getting set so the query for the grid is empty. You can do a SQL trace to confirm but I would use `CommitChange="True"` on the filter field in your page...

```
<px:PXTextEdit ID="edDisplayID" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="DisplayID" CommitChanges="True">
```

Comment: I don't get fields rendered at all, even the filter field. Very strange issue.

Comment: I created the screen in older build and imported into this one and seems to work. Something is wrong with build 17.204.0019

Answer (score 0):

It appears that FormDetail creation does not work in 17.204.0019. I created the screen in 17.202.0016 and it worked fine. I imported the screen into 17.204.0019 and it also worked. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: I would need more information to diagnose whether or not this is a bug in the product. Specifically about "When I open it, the screen is blank.". Where do you open it? Do you mean in Visual Studio window designer, in Acumatica customization project editor or in the web browser? How blank is the screen, is it completely white? There are debug tools available in the browser and Visual Studio to diagnose these kind of issues, like the debug console or output window. A completely blank page could be the result of a connection error.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA Designer works fine. It displays all the fields/grids correctly. When you open the screen in Acumatica (browser), it is almost completely white. It does show the buttons that you add, like the cancel button, then there is a grey bar under it and the rest is white. Nothing shows in Trace.

Comment: Adding an image to your question might help. From that description it could be that there is simply no data to display. One thing I noticed is that PrimaryView in PXDataSource element is set to the filter dataview: StrainFilterRec. I would have put the grid dataview there: ResponseRec. Also you can delete the EmptyMsg ASP element, whatever generated that I see no use to keep it in a production page.